# Can you transmute before taking energy tokens?

Tags: seasons

Let's say I have 7 energy tokens, and choose a die face that includes both transmutation and energy tokens.  If I tried to take energy tokens, I would lose any extra energy, because I can't hold more than 7 at once.

Can I transmute energy that is currently in my reserve, before taking the new tokens into my energy reserve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No**, as you have to to receive energy tokens from your crystal before doing anything else. From the [2nd edition English rulebook](http://en.libellud.com/index.php?option=com_zoo&task=callelement&format=raw&item_id=622&element=66b58ffc-c789-4cef-b9f1-2cb5226ebace&method=download&args%5B0%5D=8acd23046d33559746d5f0baebb8e122&Itemid=57), p. 8, emphasis mine:

> Resolution order of the actions of the player’s rounds
>
> The following actions on the Seasons dice must always be resolved before performing any other action: drawing a card, **receiving energy tokens or crystals**, increasing your Summoning Gauge. Once these actions are resolved, the players can perform their other actions, in the order of their choice.

After that, you may transmute at anytime and as many times you want during your turn.